# Can't override css of element

Tags: html, css

I have a website with a global template that contains partial templates, but now I'm stuck with a simple CSS problem:

**HTML**

```
<div id="context"> <!-- this is part of global template -->
    <!-- this is rendered by partial template -->
    <select id="test">
        <option>[Select a value]</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Global CSS**

In a global stylesheet the default width for all `<select>` elements inside `#context` is defined:

```
div#context select
{
   width: 500px;
}
```

**Partial CSS**

Now for the partial template (which renders content inside `#context`), I need to override the default width of `<select>`. I thought this would be as simple as:

```
select#test
{
    width: 150px;
}
```

But I was wrong, it doesn't work. And I guess it is because css thinks `div#context select` is a better match for the element, because it works when I change the partial template css like this:

```
div#context select#test
{
    width: 150px;
}
```

Of course, this is not what I want to do, because the partial template should not know in which node it is rendered inside the global template.

Any ideas on how I can override the style for the partial template without specifying an element from the global template?

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XvZSz/)

Comment: Maybe throw an `!important` to overcome that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is enough to make your selector just a little bit stronger:

```
body select#test
{
    width: 150px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XvZSz/2/

From [W3 - CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity):

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> - count the number of ID selectors in the selector (= a)
> - count the number of class selectors, attributes selectors, and pseudo-classes in the selector (= b)
> - count the number of type selectors and pseudo-elements in the selector (= c)
>
> [...]
>
> Concatenating the three numbers a|b|c (in a number system with a large base) gives the specificity.

So, `div#context select` is 1 ID and 2 elements: 0|1|2
But: `select#test` is 1 ID and 1 element (0|1|1) - not as strong.

More info:

- [MDN - Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)
- [Specificity Calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/)

Comment: This is it, better than important. Still ugly though. Perhaps OP should refactor his CSS and remove `div#context select`

Comment: well, since there is no `<body>` element in my partial template, I prefer not to use it in partial css.

Comment: @Wouter - CSS isn't applied to templates, it is applied to the page. But still, this is just an example: **any** change will do: you can add a class, for example.

Comment: @Wouter - as for `!important` - what will you do when you want to override an `!important` rule? Make the new rule more specific.

Comment: @Kobi yes, I understand, but in the global stylesheet, it is just a 'default' value. So it wouldn't make sense to add `!important` there.

Comment: @Kodi didn't know that `specificity` formula. This is funny: `select#test[id=test]` overrides it too because it results in 111.

Comment: @Wouter - Right! But what if you had a sub-template, and you wanted the width there to be `100px`? A class is usually easier to maintain and understand than an `!important` rule. It is the difference between a scalpel and a saw: you want to use the simpler option first. When you're mad and tired, you can say "Oh, scr#@ it all, `!important` everything!". It even has an exclamation mark, to indicate rage.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Generally you should avoid using !important except in certain cases. I till help making your code clean and will make you override it easier.

Comment: @Wouter - Awesome, you got it! Another option is to use `#context select` and `select#test`: both 101. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XvZSz/3/

Comment: @Kobi will change global to `#context select`, I think it's the more logical solution for my case.

Comment: @Wouter - Great! Good to hear. I changed the answer a little - it seems I was a little outdated, but the principle is still the same `:)`

Comment: Here's a quick test that shows CSS "isn't a calculated weight": http://jsfiddle.net/kobi/rfk5p/ . That vague comment on MDN made be re-learn this.

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
select#test
{
    width: 150px !important;
}
```

A rule that has the **!important** property will always be applied no matter where that rule appears in the CSS document. So if you wanted to make sure that a property always applied, you would add the **!important** property to the tag.

Comment: So there seem to be many sources of why I shouldn't use `!important`. Therefore, I think I'll stick with Kobi's solution and try to make the partial css a little bit stronger.

Answer (score 4):

`!important` will override your css

```
select#test
{
    width: 150px !important;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/clink/yNqwA/)

what if your global css has `!important`

Then you could call `body select#test{/*call your css*/}`

Answer (score 3):

It's not about "better match" the rule has higher specificity value
please check this [link](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

I would recommend to avoid the use of !important 
You can read about it [here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-important-css-declaration/).
Here several highlights why **not** to use !important:

1.Encourages sloppy, poorly thought-out code

2.Creates code that is less maintainable

3.Overrides styles declared in user style sheets, thus degrading accessibility

Answer (score 1):

!important will override any style.

```
select#test
{
    width: 150px !important;
}
```